# Transcribing marriage record from 1627 Winnenden

Tags: germany, palaeography, 17th-century, transcriptions, wurttemberg

This record comes from the marriage register of Winnenden, Rems-Murr-Kreis, Württemberg.

[image]

I can read most of it:

> Herr Conradt Rieger, Bürgermeister allhie, und Maria, weyland Herrn
> Johann Christoff Herpsten S(elig?) gewesenen Vogts zur ***Asang??***:
> ***Brüningen***?? hinterlassne Wittwe allhie

but the two words in bold italics make little sense to me.

First, I am not sure that I read them correctly. I believe they should be geographic locations, most likely pointing to one of the possessions of the Duke of Württemberg (else, why is Christoph Herbst a Vogt there?), but I have not been able to find anything useful. Meyer's Gazetteer does not know either location, and even though there are three hits for "Asang" near Winnenden on google maps, none of them pans out.

The location seems crucial to me to find out more about the bride, Maria, who was previously married, and who will be married again 11 years later, this time to one of my ancestors. I would like to nail down her life dates and last name at birth if that is at all possible.

Comment: what about [this](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Winnenden,+Germany/Asang,+94436+Simbach,+Germany/@48.7676886,9.066507,7.71z/data=!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x4799c9beef8dc3e5:0x9ed75e2f4c3100f0!2m2!1d9.3971423!2d48.8750046!1m5!1m1!1s0x4775a233b047c35f:0x18674c8def6faa8b!2m2!1d12.7472307!2d48.5631569!3e2?entry=ttu) >270km? Or is it too far?

Answer (score 0):

To close the loop: The two words in question have finally been deciphered. They read "Marg: Grüningen" (hard as this might be to believe at first), which turns out to be an older form of "Markgröningen", one of the residences of the dukes of Württemberg. It all makes sense now.